# Replace echo with new line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find out what the best way is to replace single echo word in a line to empty line in my script, with the sed command. Something like this:

Before:

```
echo "Hi"
echo
echo "Hello friend"
```

After:

```
echo "Hi"

echo "Hello friend"
```

I do know how to change all the echo words, but how do I change only lines including the echo command?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

This should work:

```
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*echo[[:space:]]*$/ /g'
```

Explanation:

^ matches start of line

[[:space:]]* matches zero or more white characters (this includes tabs)

echo matches just echo word

$ matches end of line

Comment: Thank, but it didn't remove them all though. Some echo commands in my script have two tabs in them, which means the `echo` looks more like `<tab> <tab>echo` . Any idea to remove them?

Comment: Try this: sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*echo[[:space:]]*&/\n/g'

This will also match white space characters before and after 'echo' word.

Comment: Still no sign of result. I also tried `sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*echo&/\n/g' ` but still, none seem to work.

Comment: Could you post some reall example data that you have?

Comment: I took a picture with my phone of it, hope that's okay. http://postimg.org/image/sxgw7e8a3/

Comment: I don't know then why this doesn't work. I will try to do this tomorrow

Comment: Don't you mean `$` instead of `&`? That would explain the problem @Tomb_Raider_Legend.

Comment: It should be enough to replace with an empty string, rather than adding another newline (which will only work on some versions of sed anyway). Also, an explanation would make your answer more useful.